# Python: Sending and Retrieving Data from a Shout-box

Tags: python, http

I'm currently using a website with a shout-box. My aim is to have a bot log into the site, and then retrieve chat logs from the shout-box in real-time and send messages if required.

Now, I'm not brilliant with web technology. Is using POST and GET values when sending and retrieving messages (this is assuming I'm logged in already with a session) the way to go about this? Or am I barking up the wrong tree? I'd be achieving this through Python preferably, or php otherwise.

Can someone please advise me on the route to take to achieve said task - even if it's just pointing me in the right direction. Sorry for the slightly open-ended question, but there's not much content covering shout-boxes in this context online.

Thanks,

Hugh

Comment: If you want to play with HTTP requests with Python a module that you might find useful is [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#).

Comment: Hi Peque, I'll take a look at this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the easiest way to interact with web pages using Python is [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).  Go with [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) if your needs are more advanced or involve javascript.

Comment: Hi mr nick, thanks for the response. I'll take a look and see if it assists me in working with shout-boxes.